# Open file from table dynamicaly with razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Hi i'm using razor to show a `Table` that contains list of file with some different details. I just want to show a file when i click on his name.

Here is my view :

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        Nom
    </th>
    <th>
        Date
    </th>
    <th>
        Uploader
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
          <a href = @Url.Action("ViewAttachment", new { fileName = item.Path }) > @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nom) </a>  


    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Uploader)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.DocumentID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.DocumentID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.DocumentID })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

In my action i send the path of my file to controller. but i don't know how to handle it.

```
public ActionResult ViewAttachment(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            return Redirect(filename);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, "Couldn't find " + fileName);
        }


    }
```

When i click it redirect me to `domain/Document/Content/myfile` but my files are in `domain/Content/myfile`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to open the file when i click on his name ?

If the file is on a location on the server that is directly accessible by the client you don't need a controller action, you could directly have the link point to this location:

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/content/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item.Path))"> 
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nom) 
</a>
```

If the file is not accessible from the client then you need a controller action to serve this file by returning a File result:

```
public ActionResult ViewAttachment(string fileName)
{
    fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName);
    string file = Server.MapPath("~/Content/" + fileName);
    if (!File.Exists(file))
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }  
    return File(file, fileName, "application/octet-stream");
}
```

And if you wanted to open the target file in a new tab you could add the `target="_blank"` attribute to the anchor:

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/content/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item.Path))" target="_blank"> 
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nom) 
</a>
```

Comment: Your solution works great but can you edit the response to show how to open the target file in new tab ?

Comment: You could add the `target="_blank"` attribute to the anchor. I have updated my answer to include this information.