# Retrive file and make it into a clickable format to open in new window or downloadable

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have save file path in db.and now i want to open the file from the path which i get from db and open it in new window.
variable defined

```
public string Attach { get; set; }
```

path recieved in Attach variable

```
ipcl.Attach = detail[0].Attach;
```

View side i want to repersent it in clickable format so that it will open in new window or downloadable.
but didn't get any idea how to do.

```
@model lay.Models.Lell
<div>attachments<input id="Rattc" type="text" value="@Model.Attach" readonly /></div><br />
```

Comment: See: [Working with Files in an ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) Site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/data/working-with-files) and [Open file from table dynamicaly with razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582487/open-file-from-table-dynamicaly-with-razor)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enable users to click on the file name to open it, create a link.

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/content/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item.Path))"> 
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nom) 
</a>
```

For further details, please see: [Open file from table dynamicaly with razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582487/open-file-from-table-dynamicaly-with-razor)